# Redis: How is the result of KEYS * sorted?

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I have a very simple php redis application which creates keys at certain events. All the keys are just counters and have an expire time of 24 hours. Basically a rolling window of 24 hours for every key to gather some statistics.

```
if ($redis->exists($key)) {
    $redis->incr($key); 
}
else {
    $redis->set($key, '1');
    $now = time(); // current timestamp
    $redis->expireAt($key, $now + 86400);
}
```

When I extract an overview of all my keys with `$list = $redis->keys("*");` (or in a redis-cli console with `keys *`), I would suspect a chronological order by creation date. However this is not case. Neither are they ordered alphabetically, by value...

So my question is, how is this list sorted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, don't use `keys *` it is debug function not designed for a production, you can kill your server...
If you need enumerate all keys in DB in safe way, use `SCAN` function with `LIMIT`.

Anyway results of `keys` or `scan` is not sorted in any manner, order of results related to internal memory structure of redis's hashtable.

About your php script, you can do it by a single command, without `exists` `set` `expireat` just run:

`SET key 1 EX 86400 NX`

`EX 86400` mean expire in 86400 (1 day) seconds from now

`NX` mean create a key only if it doesn't exists.

If this command return (nil) run regular `INCR key` its mean that the key already exists. BTW `INCR` command will not remove your expire settings.

Comment: An almost perfect reply - uproots an evil pattern, provides the answer to the question, and  and teaches proper Redis - would have upvoted twice if I could. A final pseudo PHP example of what you've described would have made it perfect ;p

Comment: Hi Itamar, have no idea what client he is using :) BTW It would be nice to have a cup of coffee on occasion in northern Tel Aviv. We are neighbours =)

Comment: Fair point about the client. I'd be happy to do it && pick the tab (assuming no dessert, naturally) - contact me and we'll make it happen.

Comment: @h0x91B I will get all the **fields** corresponding to the ```keyname``` with the command ```hkeys keyname```, so are these fields sorted?What are the **fields** sorted by?

Comment: @Pychong Basically, all of the above applies to `HSET`, you have `HSCAN` which you will use if you a big `HSET`.
Under the hood, the small `HSETs` are stored in memory as `zip-list`, so you will get the keys in the same order as you added them. 
But after passing the threshold of `hash-max-ziplist-value 512` or `hash-max-ziplist-entries 64` `HSET` will be converted to a real hash table, and then the keys will be returned to you in random order. 
More info: https://redis.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/01chapter-9-reducing-memory-use/9-1-short-structures/9-1-1-the-ziplist-representation/